# Duality in Electromagnetic Spectrum

Tags: visible-light, wave-particle-duality

Is visible light the only portion of the electromagnetic spectrum that exhibits particle/wave duality?  If so, how/why do other frequencies (i.e. radio) behave as waves?

Comment: All have the same nature , difference is that we can only see visible light only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photons of any energy are subject are described by quantum mechanical laws. As a quick example off the top of my head, [UV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet) photons participate in the [photoelectric effect,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) which is commonly used to illustrate the classical vs quantum view of light.

Radio waves are constructed of photons as well. This is difficult to directly or indirectly observe because of both their low energy. See [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10151/29216) here on Physics.SE.

For more info, see [this Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality)

Comment: Electromagnetic radiation in the radio frequency range is considered to be a constant wave, is this correct?  Light, as an electromagnetic radiation phenomena, has discrete quanta, packets, or photons that are not continuous.  Is there a subset of the spectrum that is packetized where the remainder is continuous?

Comment: @Beauness No, all the spectrum has discrete quanta, but the energy per photon is smaller at lower frequency ($E = h\nu$). So for radio waves the discreteness is harder to detect than for light. Nevertheless, radio waves come in quanta as well.

Comment: Thank you BMS & Nathan - I appreciate your explanations.